# MySQL Network connections are slow

Tags: networking, mysql

I have setup 3 machines connected to a router (over WI-FI).
I have MySQL server installed on a Core I7 Machine with good amount of memory. and am Querying from other machines to pull data from the server.

On a table with 100000+ entries, the query gets executed in 0.4 seconds on the server, however the same query takes almost 3 seconds to execute on the client machine.

What am i missing? Why the execution of same query (select * from tableName) takes so much of time, when executed from a client machine.

Thanks for the comments. 
i have tested the same query on both machines, by setting the limit to 10 rows. The time consumed is less than 0.01 MS. So, for shorter dataset's the time is inline, however when complete tables are queried, there is a significant difference in time.

My theoritical network speed is 150 MBps, but still the queries are taking much time. Any suggestions on how this could be improved? Having a switch and connecting all machines to switch? will it solve the issue?

There are no other processes running on server and on client. i have closed all applications and am trying to debug the issue with Slowness. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big is the resulting dataset from your query?  If it's huge, then it may be just transfer time to the remote machine.  If you use a more limited query (ie: `SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 5;`, or `SELECT <SpecificField> FROM tableName`) is it any faster?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Your observations were accurate. When i run the query with Limit set to 10 on both machines, the time is very much same. However, there is a huge difference when i query the complete table.

Comment: Have you tried to do as I suggested in my answer below?  (create a sproc?)  There will always be a difference, however, it may due to multiple causes.  Also, how are you querying the data on the remote PC (installed program, code run through an IDE, etc.)

Comment: This test has been performed using HeidiSQL. I have a custom application (Java & DBUtils) which extracts and processes the data from these tables. There are ~500 tables.

Comment: The application performance is worse than reported above. I am in process of optimization and fixing these issues.

Answer (score 0):

What might be missing is how you're querying the DB...  for instance, is the unknown client "pulling" all the data from the server [and perhaps locking the table as it does] & then displaying results -vs- the server only providing the data necessary [and not locking the table, or locking only internal to the server request].

With regards to both locking & the amount of data "pulled"...  it depends on how your executing the query...  with regards to locking, it depends on the default settings; because in some cases even a select query can need to lock the tables in order to ensure valid aggregation on long running queries...  Also, when you're talking JOINs, is it "joining" in local client memory or on the server?  There's a business case for both.  Usually, in cases like yours (where there is large amounts of data being operated upon) it's the ideal case for SPROCs & UDFs (user defined functions).  Have you tried to create SPROCs & UDFs?  (only passing back a result and/or status.)

What I'd try doing is to run a stored procedure (which internally has the exact same SQL as the client's "manual" SQL) from the remote PC and see if you still have such a lag.

If that doesn't solve the issue, then you really need to include more specific details on not just the query, but what "stack" your using to query it on the remote PC.

Comment: It is just a select * from tablename query. i believe this doesnt lock the table, because there arent any for update clauses in it.

Comment: Updated answer, please try some SPROCs & UDFs ... in your use case, it should resolve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

`select * from tableName` is a very vague query (get ALL data from the table).  If the table is 100000+ lines long, then the server is probably returning a lot of data.  If the total size of the returned data is large, then transferring it to a remote machine will take significantly longer than just dumping it to the local server.

Try increasing the precision of your queries so that they returns less data.  I.E., if you only need "Name" and "Address" from the table try something like `Select Name,Address from tableName` so that you're not also getting a bunch of field/data that you aren't going to use.

The (only) other way to speed it up significantly is to increase the network connection speed between the server and the client(s).

Comment: Yes. Tried it. As per the question, by adding a limit to 10 records in the query drastically improved the performance, however in application, i would be needing all of the data for processing. So, looking for a way to improvise the speed.

Comment: Theoritical network speed is above 40MB ps. The size of the table is 25MB. Ping latency is <  2ms. Still, 4 seconds is huge for one table.

Comment: I am afraid, the performance would be worse, in case of any update queries.